# Migrating python2 mixed-type np.array operations to python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, migration, numpy-ndarray, mixed-type

I'm migrating from python2 to python3 and I'm facing an issue which I have simplified to this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, None])
(a > 0).nonzero()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

In reality I'm processing np-arrays with millions of data and really need to keep the np-operation for performance. In python 2 this was working fine and returns what I expect, since python2 is not so keen on types. What is the best approach for migrating this?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @CDJB Judging by the fact that in Python 2 `None` was always "smaller" than `int`, I guess `[None, 1, 2]`, unless `numpy` did some other magic I don't recall

Comment: @CDJB which will output `array([0, 1])`

Comment: as @DeepSpace said, [0, 1]. None should be treated as smaller than int, I could handle if it was equal to 0 as well, but that would require me to do some extra checks and testing. The problem i face is that it seems to be difficult to do mixed-type operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired result is to use a lambda function with `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, None, 4, -1])
>>> f = np.vectorize(lambda t: t and t>0)
>>> np.where(f(a))
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

Of course, if the array doesn't contain negative integers, you could just use `np.where(a)`, as both `None` and `0` would evaluate to `False`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, None, 4, 0])
>>> np.where(a)
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

Another way this can be solved is by first converting the array to use the float dtype, which has the effect of converting `None` to `np.nan`. Then `np.where(a>0)` can be used as normal.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, None, 4, -1])
>>> np.where(a.astype(float) > 0)
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

**Time comparison:**

[image]

So Bob's approach, while not as easy on the eyes, is about twice as fast as the `np.vectorise` approach, and slightly slower than the float conversion approach.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

f = np.vectorize(lambda t: t and t>0)

choices = list(range(-10,11)) + [None]

def cdjb(arr):
    return np.where(f(arr))

def cdjb2(arr):
    return np.where(arr.astype(float) > 0)

def Bob(arr):
    deep_copy = np.copy(arr)
    deep_copy[deep_copy == None] = 0
    return (deep_copy > 0).nonzero()[0]

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.choice(choices, size=n),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(25)],
    kernels=[
        cdjb, cdjb2, Bob
        ],
    xlabel='len(a)',
    )
```

Comment: interesting, any guess of performance impact in comparison with my "deep copy and replace" alternative?

Comment: @Bob updated with new method and time comparision graph :)

Comment: Excellent! My uneducated guess is that that's very close to what python 2 is doing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To conclude, with the help of @CDJB and @DeepSpace, the best solution I found is to
replace the None values with a value suitable for the specific operation. Also included deep copy of array for not messing up the original data.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, None, 2, None])
deep_copy = np.copy(a)
deep_copy[deep_copy == None] = 0
result = (deep_copy > 0).nonzero()[0]
print(result)
[0 2]
```